# Multiple instances of wrapper for unmanaged code referencing same dll

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged

I'm using a managed C# wrapper to access an unmanaged C++ library. The library does some time consumung caluclations (up to 6 seconds) that I need. But also in parallel to that I continuously need some data that is fast to get too.

To achieve that, I tried to get two instances of my wrapper, one for the quick stuff and the other one in a parallel thread to calculate the time consuming information. But, as soon as I instanciate the slow one of the Analyzers, even the quick one gets slow too.

```
fullAnalyzer = new Analyzer(FullAnalysis);
miniAnalyzer = new Analyzer(MinimalAnalysis);
```

It looks like both of them are sharing the same configuration in the back, because if I instanciate the quick one first, it is still fast.

Is it in general possible to have two or more seperate instances of a wrapper accessing an unmanaged library without interfering? I so - how is it done? Or is this behaviour just a local thing of this library?

**Edit:** This is the constructor and some part of the wrapper code

```
public class ScrWrapper
{
    private const string DllName = @"Analyzer.dll";

    public bool IsConfigLoaded { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAnalyticsSuccessful { get; private set; }

    public Analyzer()
    {
        IsConfigLoaded = false;
        IsAnalyticsSuccessful = false;
    }

    public Analyzer(string configFileName, ScrProcLevel procLevel = ScrProcLevel.PL_NONE)
    {
        IsConfigLoaded = false;
        IsAnalyticsSuccessful = false;
        LoadConfig(configFileName, procLevel);
    }

    public void LoadConfig(string configFileName, ProcLevel procLevel = ScrProcLevel.PL_NONE)
    {
        if (configFileName.Length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Empty configFileName. Must contain valid file name.");

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(configFileName))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Invalid configFileName. File not found: {0}",configFileName));

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(DllName))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Invalid DllName. File not found: {0}", DllName));

        bool b_config_status = false;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(configFileName);
            ScanAuto_EnableWriteOut(true);
            b_config_status = ScanAuto_LoadConfig(sb);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ScrException("ERROR: Unmanaged Analyzer threw exception.", ex);
        }
        if (!b_config_status)
        {
            throw new ScrException(String.Format("ERROR: Failed to load the configurationfile, b_config_status=false"));
        }

        IsConfigLoaded = b_config_status;

        _ProcLevel = procLevel;
        Analyzer_SetProcLevel(_ProcLevel); 
    }       
...     


    [DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = CallConvention)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    private extern static bool ScanAuto_LoadConfig(StringBuilder _pConfigFName);

}
```

Comment: It's possible - and the way you are instantiating should be fine from the little I can see, so the issue must be in your wrapper or in the unmanaged dll.

Appreciate you may not have the code for the library, but can you post the wrapper code so that can be ruled out?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the relevant parts from the wrapper code.

Comment: I was about to ask for the DllImport bit and you added it! Your wrapper looks fine from what I can tell, so its very probably the fact that ScanAuto_LoadConfig method (and probably the members it's initialising) is static, causing it to overwrite the same bit of config each time. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I contacted the supplier of the dll to get an answer to that question.

Comment: I just got answer from the suppllier - it's indeed the librarys fault. So, if you'd like to set your comment into an answer I'd love to mark this question as solved.

Comment: have done - thanks - and hope you can get the library updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrapper looks fine from what I can tell, so its the fact that ScanAuto_LoadConfig method (and therefore the members it's initialising) is static, causing it to overwrite the same bit of config each time. see [Static Data Members (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx)